# Call function from cshtml to cshtml.cs using Models

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I am new to asp.net core and Razor, i am trying to call a function from cshtml page to his inner cs page:

```
<button onclick="@{Model.GetUserInfo(1);};" type="submit">Search</button>
```

cshtsml.cs

```
public UserInfo GetUserInfo(int userId)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = client.GetAsync($"localhost:44322/api/User/user/{userId}{userId}");
        var body = response.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserInfo>().Result;

        return body;
    }
}
```

I would like to get the information back from the api and display the information that i received.

With this code if i put { } around the Model.GetUserInfo(1); it doesn't display the button, without the { } it just doesn't compile.

Any of you can help me with it? thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what you **don't** do. The View (the CSHTML file) has to receive through the Model the entire information it needs, so the Controller (the CS file) has to ensure it has filled the Model appropriately.

Comment: OK, i see, so basically the api, i should call it when the page loads?

Comment: You can submit your post to controller, then return your view with your data. Or use JS, or maybe AJAX html helpers for example. Anything but that. Here is [example from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: One would think that when NodeJS is used by everyone with its completely asynchronous nature one would not try to write deadlocking synchronous code in other languages when they switch... But apparently it is not the case :( .. I'd strongly recommend searching for "C# async result deadlock" (use general search engine like https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+async+result+deadlock or https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+async+result+deadlock, avoid search on https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?field-keywords=c%23+async+result+deadlock or other commerce/entertainment sites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 - You can write a javascript function which will send an ajax request to your controller method

Step 2 - Return the data you want from this method

Assuming your controller name is Home, you can do something like this-

```
<button onclick="GetData()" type="submit">Search</button>

function GetData() {
    $.get("/Home/GetUserInfo", function (data) {
        // Here put what do you want from received data
    });
}
```