# .NET: Calling a cshtml.cs function in cshtml , trying to get a user input passed onto the arguments in the cshtmly.cs function

Tags: c#, .net

I have looked at these links : I am trying to pass two user inputs onto the the add function which takes two parameters. Most of the searches reference asp.net. Was looking to do it just on .net.

1. [Calling a C# function when input is changed in cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69313210/calling-a-c-sharp-function-when-input-is-changed-in-cshtml)
2. [Call function from cshtml to cshtml.cs using Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215771/call-function-from-cshtml-to-cshtml-cs-using-models?rq=1)
3. [Call function from cshtml to cshtml.cs using Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215771/call-function-from-cshtml-to-cshtml-cs-using-models)

```html
@page
@model DropdownModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Calculator";
    ViewData["Add"] = "The Calculator";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<h1>
    

    @MyPortal.Pages.DropdownModel.Addnumber.Addnumbers(3,2);

    
</h1>


<p>Use this page for a calculator project.</p>
```

```html
  public class Addnumber
        {
            public static int Addnumbers(int firstnum , int secnum)
            {
                return firstnum + secnum;

            }
        }
```

Comment: "_Most of the searches reference asp.net. Was looking to do it just on .net._" Wait. Do i understand you correctly that you want to do ASP.NET  Razor stuff _without_ ASP.NET  Razor?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to accomplish this in .NET without a POST request to the server. It probably would be easier to add the numbers with a JS function.